# Is there a better way of this MySQL CASE SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, case

The last two parameters are PHP WHERE and ORDER clauses, they (probably) don't matter here.

```
fornecedores.nome_emp AS nome_fornecedor, exchange_rates1.rate AS rateEUR_USD,
exchange_rates2.rate AS rateEUR_AOA,
CASE produtos.moeda 
WHEN 'AOA' THEN produtos.preco_custo / exchange_rates2.rate 
WHEN 'EUR' THEN produtos.preco_custo 
WHEN 'USD' THEN produtos.preco_custo / exchange_rates1.rate 
END as prc, 

CASE produtos.moeda 
WHEN 'AOA' THEN produtos.preco_venda / exchange_rates2.rate 
WHEN 'EUR' THEN produtos.preco_venda 
WHEN 'USD' THEN produtos.preco_venda / exchange_rates1.rate 
END as pvp 

FROM produtos 
LEFT JOIN fornecedores ON produtos.id_fornecedor = fornecedores.id_fornecedores 
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates AS exchange_rates1 ON exchange_rates1.para = 'USD' 
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates AS exchange_rates2 ON exchange_rates2.para = 'AOA'
$whereClause $orderClause
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the power of a `JOIN` in MySQL. You're trying to get two different exchange rates (via two different `LEFT JOIN`s to the same table) and then use the `CASE` to figure out which one to use.

Instead, join only to the rate you actually need! Then you don't need any conditional logic at all.

```
fornecedores.nome_emp AS nome_fornecedor, exchange_rates.rate, produtos.preco_custo / exchange_rates.rate
FROM produtos
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates ON exchange_rates.para = produtos.moeda
```

This assumes that there's a row in `exchange_rates` for `EUR` that has the rate set to `1`.

Comment: damn, i actually tought about it, but got stuck on if we were talking about euros, where we actually do nothing and leave it be. My exchange_rate table had not a row for EUR... Shame on me... Thanks VoteyDisciple